# How to dynamically get user location and set it to the Google Map?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, geolocation, location

I have a Google Map, where I have location marker with a radius let's say 5km, I want to place this marker on the map, where from the user is accessing the page, It is working fine with the static lat long, but giving an error with dynamic values

```js
var Circle = null;
var Radius = $("#radius").val();
var infoWindow = '';
$prevlatitude = $("#latitude").val();
$prevlongitude = $("#longitude").val();
var StartPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(28.62694276371995, 100.201416015625);

function DrawCircle(Map, Center, Radius) {
  if (Circle != null) {
    Circle.setMap(null);
  }
  if (Radius > 0) {
    Radius *= 5;
    Circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      center: Center,
      radius: Radius,
      strokeColor: "#0000FF",
      strokeOpacity: 0.35,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: "#0000FF",
      fillOpacity: 0.20,
      map: Map
    });
  }
}

function SetPosition(Location, Viewport) {
  Marker.setPosition(Location);
  if (Viewport) {
    Map.fitBounds(Viewport);
    Map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
  } else {
    Map.panTo(Location);
  }
  Radius = $("#radius").val();
  DrawCircle(Map, Location, Radius);
  $("#latitude").val(Location.lat());
  $("#longitude").val(Location.lng());
  $("input[name=gtag],input[name=space_location],input[name=tag_location],input[name=location],input[name=locations]").val($("#latitude").val() + ";" + $("#longitude").val());
}
var MapOptions = {
  zoom: 14,
  center: StartPosition,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  streetViewControl: false
};

var MapView = $("#map");
var Map = new google.maps.Map(MapView.get(0), MapOptions);

// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
Map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

Map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
  searchBox.setBounds(Map.getBounds());
});
var markers = [];
// Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
// more details for that place.
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
  var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
  if (places.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  places.forEach(function(place) {
    if (!place.geometry) {
      console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }
    var NewPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng());
    //get_lat=place.geometry.location.lat();
    //get_long=place.geometry.location.lng();
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: NewPosition,
      map: Map,
      title: "Drag Me",
      draggable: true
    });
    markers.push(Marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragend", function(event) {
      SetPosition(Marker.position);
    });

    $("#radius").keyup(function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(Marker, "dragend");
    });

    DrawCircle(Map, NewPosition, Radius);
    SetPosition(Marker.position);

    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
  });

  Map.fitBounds(bounds);
});

var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: StartPosition,
  map: Map,
  title: "Drag Me",
  draggable: true
});
markers.push(Marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(Marker, "dragend", function(event) {
  SetPosition(Marker.position);
});

$("#radius").keyup(function() {
  google.maps.event.trigger(Marker, "dragend");
});

DrawCircle(Map, StartPosition, Radius);
SetPosition(Marker.position);
});

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  var StartPosition = '';
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var pos = {
      lat: position.coords.latitude,
      lng: position.coords.longitude
    };
    StartPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(position.coords.latitude), parseFloat(position.coords.longitude5));
  });
}
```

Second is my change to get the dynamic lat long, then it says

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined"

Comment: I can't reproduce the error reported with the posted code.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, including any required HTML/CSS, in the question itself (preferably a StackOverflow code snippet).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @geocodezip, All I want a google map where user's current loction will be marked but also user can drap the marker to any place on map, But when I tried to give user's lat long
var StartPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
It is throwing the above error message

Comment: With the way you're implementing your StartPosition (in your map initialization and in geolocation) you are running into scope issues. Note that you have two StartPosition variables and that your Google map must be instantiated first. Also `position.coords.longitude5` should be `position.coords.longitude`. Please use [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) for guidance to properly implement HTML5Geolocation.

Comment: Also please check out this jsbin: https://output.jsbin.com/mavotuzidu

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/chandanbisht/cmo0wah1/16/, My problem is in between  8 to 14 number line, I hope now my problem will be clear to you all. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks. It's indeed a scope issue. Let me provide an answer with an amended jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Your `StartPosition` variable is returning `undefined` because JavaScript doesn't wait for the complete execution of `getCurrentPosition()`, so you are initializing your map and marker with an undefined position. You should always take JavaScript's execution order into account or you'll run into scope issues like this one.

Take a look at the following amended jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yh7x96ce/

Modified/new code below:

```
  // map
  var MapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    streetViewControl: false
  };
  var MapView = $("#map");
  var Map = new google.maps.Map(MapView.get(0), MapOptions);

  // marker
  var markers = [];
  var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: Map,
    title: "Drag Me",
    draggable: true
  });
  markers.push(Marker);

  // set position for map and marker
  var defaultPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(28.7041, 77.1025);
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {
      var userPos = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);
      Map.setCenter(userPos);
      Marker.setPosition(userPos);
    }, function() {
      Map.setCenter(defaultPosition);
      Marker.setPosition(defaultPosition);
    });
  } else {
    Map.setCenter(defaultPosition);
    Marker.setPosition(defaultPosition);
  }
```

You'll notice how my code uses `Map.setCenter()` and `Marker.setPosition()` once `getCurrentPosition()` is called. Both instantiations must be placed above.

**EDIT:** To include the initial Circle, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dopa4rqy/

```
  // set position for map and marker
  var defaultPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(28.7041, 77.1025);
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {
      var userPos = new google.maps.LatLng(data.coords.latitude, data.coords.longitude);
      SetPosition(userPos);
    }, function() {
      SetPosition(defaultPosition);
    });
  } else {
     SetPosition(defaultPosition);
  }
```

This is only one way to implement Geolocation and the code needs refactoring but I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @evan, it works for me, but the only problem is that, Initially it is not showing the radius circle, If I drag the location marker for the first time, radius circle start showing. Can you suggest something on it. Thanks once again for the help :)

Comment: Sure! You can replace both `setCenter` and `setPosition` with your function `SetPosition` that includes the Circle. See edited fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dopa4rqy/ Will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Glad to hear! :)

Comment: Heya @ChandanBisht friendly reminder, if this answer solved or helped you solve your issue please [accept or upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You solved my problem, thanks and I don't have much repo to upvote the answer. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Feel free to accept it if you want https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work and thank you, glad it solved the issue!